# Title: SVC-Scikit Learn issue

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling, scikit-learn, svm

I am getting this error in Scikit learn. Previously I worked with K validation, and never encountered error. My data is sparse and training and testing set is divided in the ratio 90:10

**ValueError: cannot use sparse input in 'SVC' trained on dense data**

Is there any straightforward reason and solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This basically means that your testing set is not in the same format as your training set. 
A code snippet would have been great, but make sure you are using the same array format for both sets.

Answer (score 0):

Since it cannot used sparse input on dense data, either convert your dense data to sparse data (recommended) or your sparse data to dense data. Use SciPy to create a sparse matrix from a dense one.